# Writing a simple batch file to setup a variable?

Tags: batch-file, 64-bit, x86-64

I want to write a simple batch file where i want to setup a environment variable based on the machine architecture. It is as below:

```
set ARCH=%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%
echo %ARCH%
if %ARCH%==x86 (
  set JAVA_ROOT=C:\Progra~1\Java\j2re1.4.2_13
) else (
  set JAVA_ROOT=C:\Progra~2\Java\j2re1.4.2_13
)
echo JAVA_ROOT is %JAVA_ROOT%
```

On 64-bit machine where the architecture is 'AMD64' the JAVA_ROOT will be displayed as 'C:\Progra~2\Java\j2re1.4.2_13' at the echo statement. But when i run an application that uses this file, the first value of JAVA_ROOT would be picked up 'C:\Progra~1\Java\j2re1.4.2_13'. I don't have any idea why it goes in the 'if' part even though i am running this on 64-bit Windows7. When i echoed the

Comment: By the way, if this batch file is intended to be distributed to other people (as opposed to being just for your own PC), assuming that Program Files is in C: is a bad idea. Relying on the fact that Progra~1 is 32-bit and Progra~2 is 64-bit (or vice versa) sounds pretty fishy too.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative solution which does not rely on x64 specific variables:

```
IF NOT EXIST %WINDIR%\SysWOW64\regedit.exe GOTO PLATX86
:PLATX64
ECHO PLATFORM IS X64
GOTO PLATDONE
:PLATX86
ECHO PLATFORM IS X86
GOTO PLATDONE
:PLATDONE
```

It works for me, might work for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running the batch file using `%SystemRoot%\syswow64\cmd.exe` on 64-bit Windows, perhaps because you're starting it from a 32-bit app, then `%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%` will be equal to `x86`, not `AMD64`. To detect this situation, you can use the `%PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432%` variable. Here's a [blog post with more info](http://blogs.msdn.com/david.wang/archive/2006/03/26/HOWTO-Detect-Process-Bitness.aspx).

However, if you just want to find the 32-bit Java path, you don't have to worry about that because WOW64 will take care of it for you if you use the `%ProgramFiles%` variable:

```
if "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%" == "x86" set JAVA_ROOT=%ProgramFiles%\Java\j2re1.4.2_13
if "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%" == "AMD64" set JAVA_ROOT=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Java\j2re1.4.2_13
if not defined JAVA_ROOT (
  echo Unsupported processor architecture.
  exit /b 1
)
if not exist %JAVA_ROOT%\. (
  echo Java 1.4.2_13 is not installed.
  exit /b 1
)
```

Note that I avoided the `if condition ( command ) else ( command )` form for setting `JAVA_ROOT`. This is because `%ProgramFiles(x86)%` contains parentheses, which would cause `cmd.exe` to misparse the if-statement if I used that form. For more complicated commands or more complicated conditions, using `call` to call a subroutine might be better. (Using a more expressive language would be even better, but that doesn't answer the question.)

Comment: I tried to get value of %PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432% by doing 'echo %PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432%', but i get 'ECHO is off.' Echo is not off as i do get other echo values. Is it because it is undefined? Can you please show me how to do comparison in batch syntax?

Comment: Yes, it's not defined except for WOW64, as stated by the article I linked to. Are you running your batch file from another program or from a command prompt window? Anyway, it just occurred to me that if you just use %ProgramFiles% and %ProgramFiles(x86)% instead of hardcoding paths, you won't have to worry about the WOW64 case.

Comment: I am running the batch file from another program. When i run the batch file from command prompt it works fine. But when i run it from another program, it gets architecture as x86. Your other approach doesn't work from me, because of the spaces in the Program files path.

I guess if I can find out the syntax to do the comparison and just keep the hard coded paths, my job would be done. I tried the synatx you provided above with the hardcoded paths, and it still goes inside x86 when called through another program

Comment: Did you try adding quotes around the variable when you evaluate it? I.e. `"%JAVA_ROOT%"`